# computing modulo with large numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to compute $$36^{293}\equiv \alpha \quad \text{mod}\, 1225284684$$ with a pocket calculator, but I'm not sure how to do this, because the modulus is so large. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maple answers $ 567839484$.

Answer (score 2):

Decompose the **exponent** $293$ into binary:
$$
293 = 256 + 32 + 4 + 1 = 2^8 + 2^5 + 2^2 + 2^0.
$$
Now, repeatedly square the **base**, reducing when the numbers get to big:
\begin{align}
36^2 &=& 36^2 &&=&& 1296 &\quad\equiv & 1296\\
36^4 &=& 1296^2 &&=&& 1679616 &\quad\equiv & 1679616 \\
36^8 &=& 1679616^2 &&=&& 2821109907456 &\quad\equiv & 504564888 \\
36^{16} &=& 504564888^2 &&=&& 254585726202452544 &\quad\equiv & 373060080 \\
36^{32} &=& 373060080^2 &&=&& 139173823289606400 &\quad\equiv & 914635692 \\
\vdots\quad &\\
36^{256}
\end{align}
Then, you can calculate:
\begin{align}
36^{293} &= 36^{256 + 32 + 4 + 1} \\
&= 36^{256} \cdot 36^{32} \cdot 36^{4} \cdot 36^{0} \\
&= (?) \cdot 914635692 \cdot 1679616 \cdot 1
\end{align}
Again, you can reduce after each successive multiplication.  Good luck!